# Using text to speech APIs in android application

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to use TTS (Text to Speech) APIs in my android application.Now i have one quetions - Is it support TURKISH language ?
I also want to highlight word in textview when that perticular word is being spoke.

How can i do it ?
Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it support TURKISH language

This may vary on different handsets/flavours of Android. You can check it out for yourself using the

```
   mTTS.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("tr", "TUR"));
```

---

> I also want to highlight word in textview when that particular word is being spoke.

Well you have a [TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html), to use this you have to `speak()` each word, one at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much.Does all version of android OS (1.6 and above) supports { new Locale("tr", "TUR") } ? means TURKISH language ?

Answer (score 0):

The TTS engine that ships with the Android platform supports a number of languages: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish. Also, depending on which side of the Atlantic you are on, American and British accents for English are both supported.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use Locale type variable.

> ```
>   final Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");          
>
>   tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new
>   TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onInit(int status) {
>
>              if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
>                 int result = tts.setLanguage(locale);
>                 if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
>                         || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
>                     Log.d("class name", "tts error ");
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 Log.d("class name", "tts error ");
>             }
>         }
>     });
>    tts.speak("write here what you want in Turkish", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
> ```